# Process creation from database in Websphere process server

Tags: database, websphere, websphere-process-server

Suppose we have a long running process and it is waiting in wait activity which expires in 50 days and this long running process is getting executed in IBM Websphere process server(WPS).

Now if I shutdown the WPS, it means that process that is executing in CPU will be killed. Now I start the server again, Now my question is how the process created again and how it resume from that particular activity like wait.

I know all these information regarding the activity is retrieved from the database but I am not sure how the creation  of process happen and how it resume from the activity at which we shutdown the server?

Please let me know in case you don't understand my question.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

All long running process instances and its details will be stored in WPS's internal DB. When a process waits, it is not actually waiting, but the process execution is actually in a state called "Wait". No process or thread will be actually waiting. 
Now when you stop the server, it has these details already persisted and when you start it again, it simply picks the details from DB. The process instance is not a process or thread (like a process/thread in OS/java), but instead an entity stored in internal database.